# While loop with non-constant loop conditions, but using parameter

Tags: parameters, while-loop, system-verilog

I am currently attempting to compile a shifter using two while loops. For-loops, the shift feature, and the log function are out of the question. When I attempt to compile it however, it throws a "loop with non-constant loop conditions" error at the indicated line. The while conditions at that line are i < j, where j is N-1, N being a parameter. My question is, since N is a parameter, why is it not acting constant even at compile time, and thus be considered a constant loop condition?

Here is the code:

```
module shifter(input logic [0:0] SW0, SW1, SW2, SW3, SW4, SW5, SW6, SW7, SW8, SW9, SW10,
               input logic [0:0] KEY0, KEY1,
                    output logic [0:0] LEDG0, LEDG1, LEDG2, LEDG3, LEDG4, LEDG5, LEDG6, LEDG7);
parameter N=8;          

//receive input from switches

logic [7:0] bits = '0;
logic [7:0] out = '0;
logic [0:0] move = '0;
logic [2:0] shift = '0;
logic next = 1;

always_comb
  begin
    bits[7] = SW7[0];
    bits[6] = SW6[0];
    bits[5] = SW5[0];
    bits[4] = SW4[0];
    bits[3] = SW3[0];
    bits[2] = SW2[0];
    bits[1] = SW1[0];
    bits[0] = SW0[0];
    shift[2] = SW10[0];
    shift[1] = SW9[0];
    shift[0] = SW8[0];
  end 

logic i = 0;     
logic k = 0;
logic [31:0] j = N - 1;

always@(negedge KEY0)
    begin
      k <= shift[2:0];
      do 
         begin
            move <= bits[0];
            do 
              begin 
                 bits[i] <= bits[next];
                 i <= i + 1;     
                 next <= i + 1;
              end    
            while (i < j); //<-------indicated line
            bits[7] <= move;
            k <= k - 1;
         end
      while(k > 0);
      out <= bits; 
    end

always_comb 
  begin
      LEDG0 = out[0];
      LEDG1 = out[1];
      LEDG2 = out[2];
      LEDG3 = out[3];
      LEDG4 = out[4];
      LEDG5 = out[5];
      LEDG6 = out[6];
      LEDG7 = out[7];
  end 

endmodule
```

Comment: try `i < (N-1)` instead of `i<j`

Comment: @noobuntu I tried it, it threw another error that said "loop must terminate within 5000 iterations"

Comment: That is a different error. Your simulator only allows 5000 iterations of a loop before it has to advance simulation time. You should look into your logic to see where it is getting stuck

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `j`, you can easily fix that by changing its declaration to a parameter:

```
parameter j = N -1;
```

The real problem is with `i` and that you are using a non-blocking assignment to `i`. So the `while` goes into an infinite loop because `(i<j)` never has a chance to change  - it is always 0.

You will need a different approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. `i`, `k`, and `next` are defined as single bit. They cannot hold a value higher than one. Declare them as:

   ```
   parameter j = N - 1;
   bit [$clog2(N):0] next = 1;
   bit [$clog2(N):0] i = 0;
   logic [2:0] k = 0;
   ```
2. When you assign `i`,`k`, and `next` you need to use blocking assignments (`=`). Non-blocking (`<=`) postpones the update; each loop will be evaluate `i<j`, `k>0`, `i + 1;` with their pre-`negedge KEY0` value.
3. Blocking assignments should also be used in your assignments to `move` and `bits` for the same reason as `i`,`k`, and `next`.
4. `i` and `next` needs be be set to 0 and 1 for each loop of `k`.
5. `bits` is assigned two different always blocks, therefore it can not synthesize.
6. The `k` loop cannot static unroll which also means it will not synthesize

You can resolve points 2, 3, 4, and 5 by moving the looping logic from the `always@(negedge KEY0)` into the bottom of the `always_comb` that already assigns `bits`. Then Change the non-blocking to blocking for the moved logic.

As far as I know, not every synthesizer supports while-loops. Even if your synthesizer supports while-loops, it must static unroll; a requirement for all synthesizable loops.

I'm guessing this is an assignment where your instructor asked you do do a shifter without for-loops. There are is a way to do this assignment without any loops and it can be down with significantly fewer lines of code and variables than you currently have.  I will not give you the code because I think this is homework. I will suggest that look into and compare the concepts of:

- `case` statements
- the down shift (`>>`) and arithmetic down shift (`>>>`) operators
- part-select addressing (`+:`), can also be called range-slicing

You may also want to read up on bit concatenations (ex:`{a,b}`) and replicators (ex: `{4{1'b1}}`).